# Maximal distance of a random walk before its first return

Tags: probability, reference-request, random-walk, stopping-times

The following (or at least a good approximation of it) might be well-known, but I could not find it explicitly stated:

Given a (symmetric) random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ starting at 0. Let $M$ be the largest [absolute] value it took before reaching 0 again. $M$ can clearly take arbitrarily large values, but is the expected value of $M$ infinite?

To make this a bit more formal: let $X_i$ be i.i.d. uniformly distributed on $\lbrace \pm 1 \rbrace$ and consider $S_i = \sum_{i=0}^j X_i$.
Let $T = \min \lbrace t \geq 1 \mid S_t =0 \rbrace$.
Then $M = \max \lbrace |S_j| \mid j \leq T \rbrace$.

Since the expected value of $T$ is infinite, this suggests that the same could hold for $M$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An excursion away from 0 starts with  step to $1$ or a step to $-1$. By the evident symmetry, it's enough to consider the first case. For the r.w. started at $1$, the chance to hit $n$ before $0$ is well known to be $1/n$. Thus,
$$
P[M\ge n] = 1/n
$$
and indeed $E[M]=+\infty$.

Comment: Many thanks! Hence to my surprise this does not diverge as fast as I thought. So $P(M = n) = 1/n - 1/(n+1) = 1/n(n+1)$. Could you be so king as to give a reference for this well-known equality?

Comment: You might have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin

Comment: Very nice article, but there is no mention of the estimate you mention in your answer. [This](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf) looks more like it though?

Comment: Look under "Example of Huygen's result -- Fair coin flipping".